# How to use importlib to import QApplication from PySide2 dynamically

Tags: python, class, import, module

I'm able to import a module from a directory with importlib, but I can't seem to utilize the classes correctly.

Without importlib, I can import the class as follows:

```
>>> from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication
>>> app = QApplication()
>>> print(app)
<PySide2.QtWidgets.QApplication object at 0x7fe3af6a9080>
```

But when I try to import it using importlib (which is needed for my dynamic imports), I get the following:

```
>>> import sys
>>> import importlib.util
>>> package_path = '/var/tmp/PySide2/__init__.py'
>>> spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location('PySide2.QtWidgets.QApplication', package_path)
>>> QApplication = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
>>> sys.modules[spec.name] = QApplication
>>> spec.loader.exec_module(QApplication)
>>> 
>>> app = QApplication()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

How can I get QApplication to behave the same as it does with `from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication`?

I tried some things with `importlib.import_module` and `getattr(module, class)`, but I haven't been able to understand how to use `import_module` to import a module from a specific path in the filesystem.

I'm using Python 3.5

**EDIT**
I've also tried the following:

```
>>> package_path = '/var/tmp/PySide2/__init__.py'
>>> spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location('PySide2', package_path)
>>> PySide2 = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
>>> sys.modules[spec.name] = PySide2
>>> spec.loader.exec_module(PySide2)
>>> 
>>> app = PySide2.QtWidgets.QApplication()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'PySide2' has no attribute 'QtWidgets'
```

and

```
>>> QtWidgets = getattr(PySide2, 'QtWidgets')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'PySide2' has no attribute 'QtWidgets'
```

**EDIT 2**
Here are the top-level contents of the PySide2 directory, which was installed via `python3 -m pip install PySide2==5.12.3`, and the resulting PySide2 directory was then copied to /var/tmp/

```
_config.py               Qt3DRender.pyi               QtPositioning.pyi        QtUiTools.pyi
examples                 QtCharts.abi3.so             QtPrintSupport.abi3.so   QtWebChannel.abi3.so
_git_pyside_version.py   QtCharts.pyi                 QtPrintSupport.pyi       QtWebChannel.pyi
glue                     QtConcurrent.abi3.so         QtQml.abi3.so            QtWebEngine.abi3.so
include                  QtConcurrent.pyi             QtQml.pyi                QtWebEngineCore.abi3.so
__init__.py              QtCore.abi3.so               QtQuick.abi3.so          QtWebEngineCore.pyi
libpyside2.abi3.so.5.12  QtCore.pyi                   QtQuick.pyi              QtWebEngine.pyi
__pycache__              QtDataVisualization.abi3.so  QtQuickWidgets.abi3.so   QtWebEngineWidgets.abi3.so
PySide                   QtDataVisualization.pyi      QtQuickWidgets.pyi       QtWebEngineWidgets.pyi
PySide2                  QtGui.abi3.so                QtRemoteObjects.abi3.so  QtWebSockets.abi3.so
pyside2-lupdate          QtGui.pyi                    QtRemoteObjects.pyi      QtWebSockets.pyi
pyside2-rcc              QtHelp.abi3.so               QtScxml.abi3.so          QtWidgets.abi3.so
Qt                       QtHelp.pyi                   QtScxml.pyi              QtWidgets.pyi
Qt3DAnimation.abi3.so    QtLocation.abi3.so           QtSensors.abi3.so        QtX11Extras.abi3.so
Qt3DAnimation.pyi        QtLocation.pyi               QtSensors.pyi            QtX11Extras.pyi
Qt3DCore.abi3.so         QtMultimedia.abi3.so         QtSql.abi3.so            QtXml.abi3.so
Qt3DCore.pyi             QtMultimedia.pyi             QtSql.pyi                QtXmlPatterns.abi3.so
Qt3DExtras.abi3.so       QtMultimediaWidgets.abi3.so  QtSvg.abi3.so            QtXmlPatterns.pyi
Qt3DExtras.pyi           QtMultimediaWidgets.pyi      QtSvg.pyi                QtXml.pyi
Qt3DInput.abi3.so        QtNetwork.abi3.so            QtTest.abi3.so           scripts
Qt3DInput.pyi            QtNetwork.pyi                QtTest.pyi               support
Qt3DLogic.abi3.so        QtOpenGL.abi3.so             QtTextToSpeech.abi3.so   typesystems
Qt3DLogic.pyi            QtOpenGL.pyi                 QtTextToSpeech.pyi
Qt3DRender.abi3.so       QtPositioning.abi3.so        QtUiTools.abi3.so
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're messing up the definition of modules. While `from PySide2.QtWidgets` is a module (file), `QApplication` is a definition inside of this module (a class definition).

To use `import_module`, you must give the path to the *module*. This will return a module object (as in `import PySide2.QtWidgets as module`). You can then use the module as you wish :)

Example:

```
import importlib

module = importlib.import_module('PySide2.QtWidgets')

QApplication = module.QApplication
app = QApplication()
```

- [Definition of package](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-package)
- [Definition of module](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-module)
- [Definition of importing](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-importing)

---

To import from a specific location, you can do almost as you did in the question ([Importing a source file directly](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importing-a-source-file-directly)):

```
import importlib.util

# Note that I'm using the module path, not the package path
module_path = '/var/tmp/PySide2/QtWidgets.py'

spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location('PySide2.QtWidgets', module_path)
module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(module)

QApplication = module.QApplication
app = QApplication()
```

Comment: Thanks araraonline.  If I'm not mistaken, your example will search the known paths for the PySide2 module.  How can I use it for a generic location in the filesystem?  E.g. if my PySide2 package is located in `/var/tmp/PySide2/`, how can I import PySide2 from that location and not the system one?

Comment: Sorry for taking that long. I've edited the answer to include what you asked for.

Comment: Thanks so much for the update.  In my PySide2 directory, I don't have a `QtWidgets.py` file, but I do have a `QtWidgets.pyi` and a `QtWidgets.abi3.so`.  I tried replacing `QtWidgets.py` with each of them, but neither resulted in a successful load.

Comment: I've edited my post with the contents of the PySide2 directory.  Is there something I can change to import from the .pyi file?

Comment: Oh, I'm afraid this question is beyond my knowledge. Hmm, if you just want to import things from a package at a non-default location, you can hack around `sys.path` ([example](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1jv-qTr2e03qqCHmKViWVbXVh00jb4gXY)). Other than that, I really don't know what to do.

Comment: If this solves your problem, no need to mark the answer as accepted as it doesn't actually answer the question and maybe someone can do later.